# Why is this JavaScript button click failing to call a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner of javascript.
but it doesn't work. plz help me.

I am using Microsoft VSCode.

**This is my main.html.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
  <link rel="javascript" src="script.js"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/papercss@1.4.1/dist/paper.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

  <title>Ultimate R-S-P</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login_box">
    <h1><span class="badge" id="loginbtn">main</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is script.js**

```
console.log("start!");

var loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginbtn");

loginBtn.onclick = function(){

    console.log("onclick event start");

};
```

Comment: To include javascript use <script> Tag not link Tag.

Comment: Thanks ! that's a good point !

Answer (score 2):

You need change the:

```
<link rel="javascript" src="script.js"/>
```

into:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

first choice:put script at the bottom of the body

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/papercss@1.4.1/dist/paper.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <title>Ultimate R-S-P</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login_box">
    <h1><span class="badge" id="loginbtn">main</span></h1>
  </div>
  <script>
    console.log("start!");

    var loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginbtn");

    loginBtn.onclick = function() {

      console.log("onclick event start");

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

second choice:move your script content to the window.onload=function(){}

```
window.onload = function() {

    console.log("start!");

    var loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginbtn");

    loginBtn.onclick = function() {

        console.log("onclick event start");

    };
};
```

if you choose this,you have to change your script tag

```
<link rel="javascript" src="script.js"/>
```

to

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks! now i see. 
if i want to put script between the head, i needed use the [ window.onload = function() {} // .js code]

Comment: @CrystalKim,yes,you can take control of the elements only after the document have been loaded,also,another way is put script content in 
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {},false).   window.onload is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The < link > tag defines a link between a document and an external resource.
The < link > tag is used to link to external style sheets.
The < script > tag is used to define a client-side script (JavaScript).

So, you need to change this code:

```
 <link rel="javascript" src="script.js"/>
```

into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this tag not the link tag

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Also fix your html you are missing an h1 end tag

```
<h1><span class="badge" id="loginbtn">main</span></h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Script tag as below.
You have used link tag instead of script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```

Answer (score -2):

actually i was confused.

that was location of javascript.

solution

```
<body>
    <div class="login_box">
    <h1><span class="badge" id="loginbtn">main</span>
    </div>

    **<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>**


</body>
```

i put the javascript code in the body.